# set clipboard=unnamedplus not wok

Tags: vimrc, installing

I am a newbie in vim and I added `set clipboard=unnamedplus` in .vimrc but doesn't work ,
in my previous os, I had the same problem and I fixed it by reinstalling vim using source and adding some extra argument to `./configure`
but now I forgot those arguments,
do you know those arguments?

Comment: If you're on *nix it sounds like you are referring to the need to build the GUI (vim-gtk3, vim-gtk, vim-gnome) branch. Clipboards are a GUI feature so the terminal versions of Vim don't have support for them.

Comment: @BLayer yes I'm on Linux, and I used that and that worked on the terminal version I'm pretty sure

Comment: If you're sure you have the right codebase then maybe you're referring to building `--with-features=huge`. See: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-35.10

Comment: Note that I didn't say you couldn't use clipboards with terminal . I said you need a GUI codebase .... that will have the required _libraries_.

Comment: @BLayer thank you but  I think  ```--with-features=huge``` is the default and I installed my current vim with passing that flag too

Comment: What Linux distribution and version are you using? You can typically solve this by using the appropriate package from your distro (most distros ship more than one version of Vim.) I typically recommend keeping the package from your distro (rather than building from source), since typically you get more support for languages (Python, Lua, Ruby, etc.) and you get updates (including fixes for vulnerabilities) from the distro (while if you build from source, you're on your own...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first

```
 git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git

 cd vim/src
```

delete ignored files

```
git clean -xdf
make clean
```

install python3 dev

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and these are the flags for installing vim and enabling GUI features contain clipboard support

```
./configure --enable-gui=auto --enable-gtk2-check --with-x --prefix=/usr --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-python3interp=yes --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

then
`make && sudo make install`

note: I did not pass `--with-features=huge` because its the default

if you encountered X11 header file not found error you can see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11453463/10053470